# create a Google calendar event with c# where start and end the user is asked

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

and a function that creates an event in the google calendar where the start date and end date are taken from two datatimePiker in custom format yyyy / MM / dd

```
private void GoogleAPI_Add_events()
    {
        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream =
            new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
            // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
            string credPath = "token.json";
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "Lefollie",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }

        // Create Google Calendar API service.
        var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        // Define parameters of request.
        EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("primary");
        request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
        request.ShowDeleted = false;
        request.SingleEvents = true;
        request.MaxResults = 8;
        request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;
        var ev = new Event();
        EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime();
        MessageBox.Show(dateTimeDatafine.Value.ToString("yyyy,MM,dd"));//the output in una date in 2021,02,01
        start.DateTime = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt64(dateTimeDatafine.Value.ToString("yyyy,MM,dd")));/the error in this

        EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime();
        end.DateTime = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt64(dateTimeDatainizio.Value.ToString("yyyy,MM,dd")));
        ev.Start = start;
        ev.End = end;
        ev.Summary = TextCognomeFamiglia.Text.ToString();
        ev.Description = "Description...";
        var calendarId = "primary";
        Event recurringEvent = service.Events.Insert(ev, calendarId).Execute();
    }
```

The error is System.FormatException:  incorrect output string format

Comment: I would like to obtain as output the creation of an event with google calendar through c # in which I want the event the start data of the event are chosen by the user through a datatimepiker

Comment: Plase don't describe it but show it. You only mention "The error is incorrect output string format". What is your current output and what do you want to get? Edit that information into your question.

Comment: I updated the question with the output and where the error is

Comment: If I get you right, you want 2021/02/02 but you get 2021,02,02. Correct?

Comment: I just want to pass this data for the creation of the event but if I put a string it only accepts it with the comma I put the comma if you have other solutions to get to the creation of the event with start and end date set by the user let me know

Comment: But isnt datatimepiker used for web applications? your coding an installed application.  if your going to just run this as a console app then you could use console.readline and hope that they put it in the corect format.   Other wise your looking at creating a whole windows [winforms page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/datetimepicker-control-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#:~:text=The%20Windows%20Forms%20DateTimePicker%20control,arrow%20next%20to%20the%20list.).  Either way i dont think there is enough information here.

Comment: and a windows form function in c # i am creating dj fix it